# How to delete files (Kill) VB

Tags: vb.net, kill, antivirus

i'm creating a anti-virus and I'm having a little trouble deleting the viruses. Here is my code:

```
If threatsLb.Items.Count > 0 Then
    threatsLb.Enabled = True
    Dim KillFile As String
    KillFile = threatsLb.SelectedItem
    If Len(Dir$(KillFile)) > 0 Then
        SetAttr(KillFile, vbNormal)
        Kill(KillFile)
    End If
End If
```

Basically, if there is a virus then the address of the virus will be stored in a list box. But the 'KillFile = threatsLb.SelectedItem' isn't selecting any of the items in the list box. I know I'm doing something wrong... can you guys help? thanks!

Comment: System.IO.File.Delete( FileToDelete )

My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(ADDRESS_OF_FILE_AS_STRING)

Comment: That's ***not how you remove a virus...***

Comment: Did you select an item?

Comment: Quite often, you'll find that viruses resist being killed and have other code hidden away to restart the file that has been killed. I'd leave it to the anti-virus companies to be brutally honest.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how you remove viruses but here you go.

```
If threatsLb.Items.Count > 0 Then
   For Each KillFile As String In threatsLb.Items
     If Not KillFile = "" Then
        SetAttr(KillFile, vbNormal)
        IO.File.Delete(KillFile)
     End If
   Next
End If
```

This will delete every files in your ListBox.

> Note that KillFile has to be the location of the file (ex: "C:\myfile.txt")